# Should I only rely on Ruby on Rails' validation mechanism to maintain uniqueness of columns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was testing my model, which has two unique attributes, in my Ruby on Rails project today.

Sadly, shoulda matcher fails my `should validate_uniqueness_of` test because it is doing a save operation with this attribute, while another attribute fails the save because of null value.

This makes me ponder:

#### Should I remove the null checks on any unique columns (specifically) in the database and solely rely on Rails' validations to prevent duplicated value in these columns?

I am using Rails 4.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No, at least not if you want uniqueness to be guaranteed** as `validate_uniqueness_of` doesn't truly ensure what its name implies.

There are a couple of reasons for this. First, certain ActiveRecord actions, such as `update_column`, `toggle`, etc will bypass validations. Second, `validates_uniqueness_of` isn't threadsafe, so two save events of the same value in separate transactions can create records if they're committed to the database at the same time.

Additionally, `validates_uniqueness_of` will run a `SELECT` statement to check if the value already exists which adds a small amount of overhead to the amount of time it takes to save a model.

Comment: Is this statement applying other validations too such as "validates_format_of" for `email` field for example? Because `update_column` will skip this check and I can potentially end up with non-email values into my email columns anyway, so does this mean that I have to add all the constraints in `model.rb` again in my database migration files?

Comment: It's true that validates can be skipped as you say, but `validates_format_of` doesn't need to do a database lookup, so doesn't have the threadsafety issues that `validates_uniqueness_of` has. As long as you're careful not to skip validations when saving, then using `validates_format_of` should be fine. Also, I don't think all database types can validate on a regex, though Postgres can.